# Java File Copy -How to Backup/copy the input file to other destination location?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, file-copying

Want to copy/backup the file  to destination folder before performing 
     any task.
    (jdk -1.7)

---

```
 /*Input file path taken from properties file as string is :inputFile
where-in inputFile is :C:\\Project\\input\\filename.txt
Destination file path taken from properties file as string is : 
archiveFolderPath */

  //Existing code : in main
if (inputFile != null) {
readTextFile(new File(inputFile)); }

// in readTextFile method
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

---

I tried using  the below procedure:: but getting an error:
Error:: 
    The method copy(InputStream, OutputStream) in the type Files is not 
     applicable for the arguments (String, String)

```
//Calling method in main::
copyFiles(inputFile, archiveFolderPath);


//Copy method :
private static void copyFiles (String inputFile, String 
  archiveFolderPath) throws IOException {
    Files.copy(inputFile, archiveFolderPath); }
```

please suggest an Alternative solution as"Files is not applicable for the 
    arguments (String, String)" .

Comment: I think the error message is pretty explanatory - you can't pass a `String` to the method, you must pass a `InputStream` (which is the source) and `OutputStream` (which is the destination).  This is basic I/O handling. You also need to consider the concept that `String` is meaning less and may mean a number of different things, so the API forces you to do some prep work first, making it more flexible, less ambiguous and easier to apply to different situations

Comment: I "suggest" you start by taking a look at [Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and consult the [JavaDocs for the `Files` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy the file before performing read or write operations on them. Example:-

```
Path origin = Paths.get("/home/fm/source.txt");
Path destination = Paths.get("/home/fm/source.bak");

//Copy source.txt to source.bak
Files.copy(origin, destination, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Refer to `Files` javadoc for all `copy` methods detail. Some of them expecting `CopyOption` as arguments. Choose suitable `CopyOption` according to program requirements.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html#COPY_ATTRIBUTES

Comment: It should be noted that one cannot pass a directory to `Files.copy`.  As [the documentation suggests](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29), it will be necessary to resolve the directory to a file name, for example `Files.copy(inputPath, archivePath.resolve(inputPath.getFileName()), …)`.